# Visual Studio recent file path

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2012

We use Visual Studio for coding across multiple solutions and workspaces. One way that I was easily able to reopen a solution in a different workspace than one I have open was to right click the Visual Studio icon and there would be a list of the recently opened solutions. This worked great!

The issue is that all of the workspaces have solutions of identical names. So if I have `Workspace1/Test.sln` and `Workspace2/Test.sln` then they both show up as `Test.sln`. In Windows 7, this was fine because I could mouse over the solution name and it would tell me its path, `C:/Workspace2/Test.sln`.

In Windows 10, this is no longer the case. I can still mouse over and see the recent solutions, but I can't see what their paths are, so it's just a field of `One.sln, One.sln, Two.sln, One.sln` with no way to tell them apart.

Is there any way to get it to show the full paths, at least on mouse over?

I know one solution to get around the problem is to make a path tree for the workspaces and rely on that, but it's nice to not have to remember which workspaces I had been using recently and just go look at the recent history, so this is preferable.

Comment: Visual studio 2015 update 2 on windows 10 still has this behavior, at least on my box.

Comment: Forgot to mention that it's Visual Studio 2012 (we're a little behind on the VS versions). If that's the case then maybe this just needs to be brought to their attention.

Comment: Weird. On mine, I see the base file name (no extension), followed by the folder path. Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.

Comment: @PatrickS. as updated, I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Update 4, though I don't see anything to hint that Update 5 fixes this.

Comment: @Nate, that's true, but Stefan is using the same version I am, and we have different results.

Comment: @PatrickS. Ah, i misunderstood what you were saying. My mistake. That is interesting though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some recent update, likely to Windows, this seems to have resolved itself. There have been a number of updates applied since I posted this, and I'm not sure exactly which one it is, but I am fully up to date as of the posting of this answer, including the Anniversary update.